# If else statement in .env file

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables

I am trying to set the URL dynamically in .env file depending on my working branch. Is it possible to use If Else statement inside .env file? I also would like to read the ENV variable from the windows environment variables.

Anyways, I am working with a react app.
Here is What I have tried but didn't work:

```
ENV = 'develop'

REACT_APP_BASE_URL = ''    
if(ENV == 'develop'){
    REACT_APP_BASE_URL = 'https://api.dev.myurl.com'
}else if(ENV == 'staging'){
    REACT_APP_BASE_URL = 'https://api.staging.myurl.com'
}else if(ENV == 'production'){
    REACT_APP_BASE_URL = 'https://api.pro.myurl.com'
}
```

Comment: Depends what you use to load the env file with. But in general, no. Usually the env files are loaded as plain variable declarations.

Comment: Wouldn't you use different `.env` files per environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нi Dev. Rafiq,

I personally resort to utility functions for that purpose.

Example, `/utils/url.ts`:

```
export const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
export const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
export const isStaging = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'staging'
export const websiteUrl = isProduction
  ? 'https://api.pro.myurl.com'
  : isDevelopment
  ? 'https://api.dev.myurl.com'
  : 'https://api.staging.myurl.com'
```

Instead of using the `REACT_APP_BASE_URL` environment variable, you could simply use `websiteURL`.

You might benefit from making these variables exportable elsewhere.

Example: If you'd wish to render a particular element only in staging then you could reuse `isStaging` as such — `isStaging && <MyElement/>`.

This approach could also be beneficial when scaling up your application, typically to use different API keys for different purposes like, Google Analytics, reCAPTCHA...etc Since it's not recommended to mix production data with staging.

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer. I think this can do what I have wanted.

Wanna ask for more help, How do I read OS environment variable inside .env file or .js file? I couldn't find something related to this.

Comment: You are welcome :) That's what we are here for!
Not sure if this is what you are looking for but I use the following syntax on my CRA projects within js files: `process.env.REACT_APP_PUBLIC_NAME_OF_MY_VARIABLE` , there is a package called `dotenv` I also use for that, in my `App.js/ts` with `require("dotenv").config()`

Comment: I was asking about the windows env variables. E.g: JAVA_HOME. Is it possible to read these variables inside react app??

Comment: I understand your question more clearly now. I am trying to figure this out since I never used this feature before. At first glance, I think you could resort to NodeJS' `OS` object as described here: https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#osuserinfooptions. `os.homedir()` reportedly gives you access to your system's env variables